# Is it possible to integrate a Firebase Authentication API in a custom Node.JS server?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication

I'm building a website that showcases an artist's works and their price, but without giving the possibility of buying products directly from the website.

It's frontend (made using React) and backend (made using **Node.JS**) are almost done, and the last feature I want to implement is a **user authentication system**, that allows the admin to modify and add products and the normal users to make wish lists.

I'm wondering if it is possible to integrate a Firebase Authentication API in the custom Node.JS server I've made.

I've tried to search for answers on the internet but I only found Firebase tutorials where it is integrated in a new project, and not in an already functioning app.

Comment: It is 100% possible , but since you have a running project I'd advice you to take a look at auth0

Comment: Do you have any authentication on frontend already? how do you store user's wishists.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, SecurityObscurity, I will look forward to it.

Comment: Dharmaraj, I don't have any authentication system implemented in my app, and I want to implement the CRUD features only after I implement the authentication system.